# Сохранение активной вкладки после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

**Select.cshtml**

```html
<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active" id="class1">
            <a href="#tab_1_1" class="tbs" data-info="class1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                1 класс
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="class2">
            <a href="#tab_1_2" class="tbs" data-info="class2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                2 класс
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="class3">
            <a href="#tab_1_3" class="tbs" data-info="class3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                3 класс
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab_1_2">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Work201615/_PartialClass1.cshtml")
    </div>

    <script type="text/jscript">
    $('.tbs').on('click', function () {
        var info = $(this).data('info');
        switch (info) {
            case 'class1':
                $('#tab_1_2').load("/Work201615/Class1"); //Controller method which returns partial view
                break;
            case 'class2':
                $('#tab_1_2').load("/Work201615/Class2"); //Controller method which returns partial view
                break;
            case 'class3':
                $('#tab_1_2').load("/Work201615/Class3"); //Controller method which returns partial view
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

**_PartialClass2.cshtml**

```html
<body>
...
    <div class="class1">
        <p></p><a href="~/Files/2_кл_Формы для внес. результатов.xlsx">Формы для внесения результатов</a></p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Work201615", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="file" name="upload" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
        }
    </div>          
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Work201615Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    if(upload!=null)
    {                
        //получаем расширение файла                
        string fileExten = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);
        //сохраняем файл в папку Files в проекте
        upload.SaveAs(@"\\192.168.88.220\файлы_пто\" + User.Identity.Name + fileExten);
    }           
    return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Select") + "#tab_1_2"); //Это не помогает

}
```

Необходимо, чтобы после загрузки файла происходил рендиринг на ту же вкладку.

Я пытался с помощью `return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Select") + "#tab_1_2");`, но это ничего не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как это работает у меня:

Представление:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Программы", "GetProgramList", "Operations", new { operationId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Tabs" }, new { @data_target = "#Tabs", @data_toggle = "tab" } )</li>
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Файлы", "GetAttachmentList", "Operations", new { operationId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Tabs" }, new { @data_target="#Tabs", @data_toggle = "tab" } )</li>
</ul>
<div id="Tabs"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {

    $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show')
    });

    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');

    // load content with ajax before show selected tab
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (result) {
                $(target).html(result);
            }
        })
    })

    // for bootstrap 3 use 'shown.bs.tab', for bootstrap 2 use 'shown' in the next line
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        // save the latest tab; use cookies if you like 'em better:
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    // go to the latest tab, if it exists:

    if (lastTab) {
        $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
    } else {
        lastTab = $('#myTabs a:first').attr('href');
        $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

при выборе любой вкладки, запоминаю её в `localStorage`, при перезагрузке страницы проверяю наличие сохраненной вкладки, если такая есть, то средствами `ajax` загружаю необходимый контент.

За основу взял решение [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524697/5610621)